# SOQL Implications of Using Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries

Tags: managed-package, governorlimits

I am a big proponent of using Andrew Fawcett's [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) tool. However, I need to have a better understanding of how it affects my governor limits.

Specifically, I have an org where `SOQL Statements` are in short supply and I would like to understand how many queries a rollup will use for a Real Time Count rollup.

I found [this link](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm#certified_pkg_limits_section) which indicates the package may be totally exempt from most limits, but I can't find his package on the AppExchange to determine if it is "Certified" or not.

Comment: Adrian -- you can post questions on Andrews's GIT site via `Issues` link and get authoritative answer. Note that `dlrs` will update your parent object so any triggers that execute on the parent obj will fire. I ran into this issue when we added dlrs and had to rework some parent obj triggers

Comment: Done. I still like this forum is an appropriate place to have this question/answer. @crop1645, do you think I should remove it?

Comment: Yes the parent triggers are a mess and that's why I'm wondering how many will be added by `dlrs` to compare with what we are removing and assess if the switch would improve or degrade the situation. They're not the most optimized as is...

Comment: There is one dlrs trigger per child object. If you have n dlrs 'directives' defined for a given child object, the dlrs trigger on the child runs only once, doing n updates on the parent so (I think), the parent trigger executes only once

Comment: Oops I meant how many queries are added. I know it only adds one trigger per object.

Comment: i would think 1 query per dlrs directive -- since you have to provide the `where clause` in the directive.  debug log would confirm this

Comment: But in addition to the directive it may also query for the sibling records, parents, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fawcett responded to my inquiry:

> Yes this is an Aloha package, it was certified back at v1.2, you can see the [README](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries#packaged-release-history) (scroll down to v1.2 section) for details. Thanks!

So it definitely does not affect `SOQL` and `DML` governor limits.